# Angular. ng serve. Module build failed. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

Tags: angular, ng

I have the following error when running "ng serve":

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\sheil\Desktop\Temp\angular-tut\node_modules@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\sheil\Desktop\Temp\angular-tut\node_modules@angular\platform-browser\fesm2022\platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\sheil\Desktop\Temp\angular-tut\node_modules@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tut",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25496) related to `@babel/traverse`.

The temporary workaround is to override the dependency in `package.json` :

```
"overrides": {
    "@babel/traverse": "7.22.6"
},
```



<del>A fix is being worked on by the babel team, the issue can be [tracked here][2].</del>

---

Edit:
`babel` `7.22.8` has been published. Delete your `package-lock` and do a clean install !

Comment: The temporary work arround is no longer necessary with the release of `babel` `7.22.8`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler So I should delete "overrides", delete "package-lock.json" and then run "npm install"?

Comment: yes that should do it !